# Saving an image using Nokogiri

Tags: css, ruby, image, nokogiri

I'm using the following piece of code to scrape specific images from a webpage. There are multiple images on this page with the image tag, so how does this code interpret that? I've noticed that it saves only the first image with the image tag. Is this true in general?

Am I correct in reasoning that this code starts reading the css from top to bottom and once it finds the first image with the image tag it saves it and stops looking further? Because I need it to do just that.

```
PAGE = "http://example.com/page.html"
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
html = Nokogiri.HTML(open(PAGE))
src  = html.at('.image')['src']
File.open("foo.png", "wb") do |f|
    f.write(open(src).read)
end
```

Comment: This just grabs the first `.image` element and downloads the `src` attribute. It doesn't care about all images. If it did you'd use the `css` method instead of `at`. You probably want to use `.css('img')`.

Comment: Do you want to find elements with the class `image` or all `img`s?

Comment: This question no longer makes sense because example.com is off-line so the example code will fail. Please see "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

- `html.at` finds the first matching element only
- `html.search` find all matching elements

Does that answer your question?

---

On a related note,

- `html.at(".image")` finds any element with `class="image"` even if it were eg a `<div>` tag
- `html.at("img.image")` finds the first `<img>` element with `class="image"`
- `html.at("img")` finds the first `<img>` element